# Bind properties/events to content children in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component `ns-form-group` which has a `sum` variable and a `computeSum()` function. Its markup is this. I want this to be a reusable component.

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

As content children, I want to pass instances of my `ns-form-row` component

```
  <ns-form-group>
    <ns-form-row [sum]="sum" (textChanged)="computeSum($event)"></ns-form-row>
  </ns-form-group>
```

and place the above markup in **app.component.html**. I do not know how to bind the input property and the event of ns-form-row with the variable and the function of the ns-form-group component. Can you help, please?

Comment: Can you tell me what problem you are facing?

Comment: I have the above markup in the app.component.html. This is where I want the ns-form-group component to appear. However the ns-form-row content child needs to be fed with a sum property and an event handler for the textChanged event. These though are inside the ns-form-group component, not the app component.

Comment: You can put `<ns-form-group>...</ns-form-group>` in your app.component.ts file right? So are you getting some error?

Comment: It's in the app.component.html file. I want to have a few ns-form-group components in there and each one having their own set of ns-form-row components.

Comment: Still, you can use multiple times `<ns-form-group>...</ns-form-group>` in your app.component.ts file

Comment: That is my purpose, to use <ns-form-group>...</ns-form-group> multiple times. However the problem is with its content children. Each ns-form-row expects a property and an event to be bound. These are available inside the ns-form-group component. So I get the squiggly lines here -> [sum]="sum" (textChanged)="computeSum($event)"

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by changing my markup to

```
<ns-form-group>
 <ns-form-row></ns-form-row>
</ns-form-group>
```

and then I managed to manipulate the state of the ns-form-row components by iterating a querylist of those content children in the AfterContentInit event of the ns-form-group component.